# Looking for locations of childcare facilities in Spokane, Washington

Tags: data-request

Someone has proposed an ordinance banning homeless camps in Spokane within a thousand feet of "parks, schools, and childcare facilities".  He admits that he hasn't made a map of the areas that would be affected, so I'm looking to rectify that situation.

Parks were easy: the city of Spokane publishes a "parks" dataset through their open data portal.  Schools were nearly as easy: I exported them from OpenStreetMap, since they've got both public and private schools, where the city's data only has public ones.

Childcare is proving to be difficult.  OpenStreetMap has nothing.  The city doesn't appear to have any data on the subject, and the closest thing I've found in Spokane County data is parcel data with a usage classification of "Service - Education", which is both overly broad and omits childcare facilities that are not the primary user of a parcel.  The state might have something, but unlike the city and county, the state doesn't have a single unified GIS or open data portal.

I'm looking for any zero-cost source of data that's better than what I've currently got.  Ideally it would be in a format that I can just open directly with QGIS, but I'm pretty good at beating data into shape.

In terms of accuracy/completeness, I'm mainly looking to answer the question "would this cover so much of the city as to be effectively a prohibition?"  I suspect the answer is "no, but it does effectively force homeless people out of the urban core and the poor parts of town, and into the upscale parts", and I'd like to make an actual map demonstrating this.